# Hide span (or div) until javascript completes

Tags: javascript

I'm using the Unit PNG Fix (http://labs.unitinteractive.com/unitpngfix.php) to make a transparent png work in IE. It's being used on the background image of my logo container.

So I have my html, which contains these relative items. In the head:

```
<!--[if lt IE 7]>
        <script src="/assets/script_unitpngfix.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

Then in the body:

```
<a href="index.html" style="display:block;"><span id="Logo"></span></a>
```

Since, the logo loads with a gray box around it before the Unit PNG Fix works its magic, how can I just hide the entire span until after the javascript is executed, so the user never sees the gray box?

Thank you.

Answer (score 10):

Instead of your current span put this:

```
<span id='Logo' style="display:none"></span>
```

And then attach this function to the body onload event (`<body onload = "showMySpan()">`):

```
function showMySpan() {
  var mySpan = document.getElementById('Logo');
  mySpan.style.display = "";
}
```

Comment: better mySpan.style.display = ''; to revert the display property to the css default value.

Comment: I agree. At first I've written it like this but edited it before posting. Now I will edit again. :)

Answer (score 3):

Keep the `span` hidden by default:

```
<span id="Logo" style="display:none;"></span>
```

Then add a piece of JavaScript to show it later:

```
document.getElementById('Logo').style.display = 'inline';
```

The best way to ensure (at least in IE) that this piece of code is executed after the PNG Fix is to put it in a separate JS file and load it as a deferred script at the end of your page:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="show_span.js" defer="defer"></script>
```

More details on deferred scripts: [JavaScript: Defer Execution](http://www.websiteoptimization.com/speed/tweak/defer/)

Comment: better document.getElementById('Logo').style.display = ''; to revert the display property to the css default value.

Comment: The **WORST** place to put the command is in the PNG Fix. You don't have to mix library and implementation code.

Comment: If you don't, you have no idea when PNG Fix has done its job, so you might end up with a gray box again.

Comment: I can't put in the javascript because it's only being called for IE, so the logo would never show in any other browser.

Comment: Isn't that a reason to use something like jQuery's ready function (or similar in another framework), which isn't equivalent to onload?

Comment: These all seem like good answers, but the logo only loads about a quarter of the way with them before getting cut off.

Comment: I overlooked the conditional script part. A deferred script might help you here - I've updated the answer to include that.

Comment: Thanks everyone. Like I said, there's some weird glitch that's causing only the top part of the logo to show when using any of these solutions. So I think I'll just tolerate the gray box.

Comment: Upon further tinkering, I just had to include the height of the logo container to keep the image from getting cut off at the seemingly arbitrary point. So even though I had defined the height in the css, I had to add to the javascript the following:

document.getElementById('Logo').style.height = '92';

But I'll try uploading it to my site to see how it works. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

You could use something like [jQuery](http://www.jquery.com/) and its [ready](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) function, which is specifically designed to wait for the DOM to be loaded.

The HTML would use `display:none` to start with :

```
<span id="Logo" style="display:none;"></span>
```

Then, add a script like this (assuming you've linked to jQuery too):

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#Logo").show();
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would go by using jquery, or other js framework and then using casablanca's solution in a 'document.ready' or something like it.

It's never healthy to trust browser's loading time/order.